# Compare dev/prod databases functions

Tags: postgresql, functions, plsql

I have two databases - dev and prod. I modify logic and debug in dev then pull everything to prod. A significant part of my app are PostgreSQL PL/pgSQL functions. I write them in dev, test, make sure they do what's expected, then move to prod.

But, I cannot be 100% sure that a prod function is the same as dev function until I delete prod one then copy/paste and recreate from dev.

So, is there a way to compare functions from two databases and know if they are the same or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Examiner](https://www.sqlaccessories.com/sql-examiner/) is a helpful tool for comparing databases, with the granularity of being able to compare just a particular function, for example.

Forewarning, it's not free, and I am not affiliated with it in any way. I'm just a user of the software for a while now, and it works well. It supports multiple database systems too.

Answer (score 0):

PG Admin has a Schema Diff tool. It is under Tools -> Schema Diff. It doesn't appear to be very robust in terms of filtering, i.e. you can't choose specific objects or object types. It compares an entire schema, which I would assume, depending on your schemas could take a while.

A link to the documentation: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/7.4/schema_diff.html

You could also look into a tool that handles database deployments for you, such as something like Flyway. I haven't used it much, but it works alright. Something like that may help track what is deployed and where.